# Javascript / Angular JS 1.x : Promise Cause Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, async-await

The code below is a function that's called to enable/disable an html element in an AngularJS application. The issue is that when this code runs it gets stuck in an infinite loop on the line with **await**.

In fact, it's stuck on the same **line** of data (the parameter), i.e., when this code runs, as soon as the line with **await** executes, it jumps right back to the function call itself.

Any ideas as to why this behavior is happening?

```
async function isXaasFieldDisabled(line) {
  let disabled = true;
  const _mfg1 = 'XXXXX';
  const _mfg2 = 'YYYYY'; 

  if (line.productPrice.manufacturerName.toUpperCase() === _mfg1) {
      disabled = false;
  } else if (line.productPrice.manufacturerName.toUpperCase() !== _mfg2) {
      const product = await CatalogService.getProduct(line.productPrice.productId);
      disabled = !!_.find(product.attributeValues, v => v.productAttribute.name.toUpperCase() === 'ABC123');
  }
  console.log(disabled);

  return disabled;
}
```

Comment: how is call the function isXaasFieldDisabled ?

Comment: It's called as "...ng-disabled='isXaasFieldDisabled'"